# Regression fails if predictor variance is small but mean is nonzero 

Tags: r, regression

R linear regression seems to fail if my predictor variance is very small, but nonzero:

```
> reg = lm(V1~V2,data)
> summary(reg)

Call:
lm(formula = V1 ~ V2, data = data)

Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-15.968  -4.898   1.627   5.218   8.468

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  11.7963     0.6036   19.54   <2e-16 ***
V2                NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Here is an excerpt from my data... (it comes out this way after boxcox...)

```
> print(data$V2,digits=15)
 [1] -0.640196668095416 -0.640196668115515 -0.640196668075674 -0.640196668083867
 [5] -0.640196668103316 -0.640196668073982 -0.640196668094188 -0.640196668081038
etc
```

And here is the regression working if I manually remove the mean value:

```
> shifted = data$V2+0.640196668
> shifted
 [1] -9.541601e-11 -1.155150e-10 -7.567402e-11 -8.386702e-11 -1.033160e-10
 [6] -7.398204e-11 -9.418799e-11 -8.103807e-11 -8.288503e-11 -9.411305e-11
etc

> reg = lm(data$V1~shifted)
> reg

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      shifted
  6.308e+00   -5.771e+10
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm using `lm` wrong?  Thank you...

Comment: Please don't "move" questions on your own -- better flag it for mod to do the migration.  And ask a separate Q for your other problem (I've removed it, but the contents are still in [edit history](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/21043/revisions)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem with the regression seems to be due to [floating point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). The reason is that the estimator of the regression coefficient for the predictor is $(\bar{xy}-\bar{x}\bar{y})/(\bar{x^2}-\bar{x}^2)$, where $\bar{x^2}-\bar{x}^2$ is the "sample variance" of the predictor (I'm using quotation marks since $x$ is assumed to be known without measurement error and variance is used only when randomness is involved). With floating point arithmetics, it seems that $\bar{x^2}-\bar{x}^2=0$ in your case, causing this problem. Shifting it by the (rounded!) mean happens to solve this problem. Such are the wonders of floating points...

What I think that you should worry about is why your data looks like that after the Box-Cox transformation. I've never used `powerTransform` myself, so I'm not sure if that function is the problem. Have you tried `boxcox` in `MASS`?

Comment: I suspected floating point precision was the issue.  I was kind of hoping there would be a regression function that can deal with such issues - e.g. shifting the data if necessary.  Is there?

Comment: `MASS` `boxcox` gives me a plot of likelihood for each possible lambda.  `powerTransform` just gives the most likely lambda, which is what I'd rather have.

Comment: The practical solution to this was to scale all my data before running `powerTransform` and `lm` (as well as removing variables with no variance, which I was doing already).  

Obviously result coefficients needed to be interpreted differently but that's ok.  This solved all power transform and regression problems over a huge number of variables (around 30,000).

Answer (score 1):

The `scale` function in `R` will by default subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation (you can turn off or change either of those).

The `bct` function in the `TeachingDemos` package will do the Box-Cox transform including the scaling in the original paper which leaves the data on a similar scale as the original.  It does not tell you which $\lambda$ to use, but if you find a value of $\lambda$ using another tool, `bct` will do the transform.